# 2 monitors - ati radeon 6800 series

Tags: display, amd-radeon

I have a question/problem. Someone bought me a new monitor and I want now to have 2 since my old one is still working. I've searched a bit and it seems my graphic card, ATI Radeon 6800 series, can have up to 2 or 3 monitors but I have a problem.

When I try to insert the second cable ( both cables are DVI and I have 2 adaptors- since  the cables don't fit on the computer entrance) the computer doesn't recognize it. I think it doesn't because I don't hear that sound that the computer makes when you insert something like a pen, monitor w/e and so my question is: do I have to maybe turn some cable inside the computer that might be turned off so the second slot of the graphic card might recognize it? I've treed to look inside and the second one seems to really be also in the graphic card.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Computers don't make sounds when you plug in monitors

Comment: What kind of adapters are you using? What connection is available on the monitors?

Comment: My OS is windows 7. Its the only one avaible: Belkin DVI p/VGA and yes they do make noise since when I insert the adaptor to the slot it makes the same sound as a pen does when I insert it on the front slots.